# Mybatis custom mapping

Tags: mybatis

I have defined a Java bean like this:

```
public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
    // getters and setters ...
}
```

give a following query:

```
select id, name, age, address from users;
```

I want to map "id" and "name" column to the Person class's "id" and "name" property, but map "age" and "address" column into the "properties" map as key-value pair.

Is this possible with mybatis? I am using the newest version of mybatis.

Answer (score 0):

Following should do what you expect:

```
<resultMap id="personResultMap" type="Person">
  <id property="id" column="id"/>  
  <result property="name" column="name"/>
  <association property="properties" javaType="map">
    <result property="age" column="age"/>
    <result property="address" column="address"/>
 </association>
</resultMap>
```

With implicit mapping (column -> property name matching), following could even be enough:

```
<resultMap id="personResultMap" type="Person">
  <association property="properties" javaType="map" />
</resultMap>
```